# Question on Regular Bipartite Graphs and Coloring

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, bipartite-graphs

Here is a question I am stuck on:
Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with partite sets $U$ and $W$ where $\Delta(G) = r \ge 1$ and $\delta(G) < r$.
Show that if there is an $r$-regular bipartite graph $H$ containing $G$ as a subgraph such that at least one of the partite sets of $H$ is $U$ or $W$, then $\chi′(G) = \Delta(G)$. Here $\chi'(G)$ refers to the edge chromatic number for edge coloring.

Why should this even be true?
[image]

Doesn't this contradict the claim? If not, is there any way I can prove this? If so, how? And finally, is there a bipartite graph with edge chromatic number greater than $\Delta(G)$?

Notation:

$\Delta(G)$ is max degree, $\delta(G)$ is min degree and partite sets refer to the two sets of vertices in bipartite graphs such that in each set, no two vertices are adjacent

Comment: Your example doesn't contradict the theorem unless you display a $2$-regular bipartite graph that contains the example graph as a subgraph.

Comment: @saulspatz But isn't my graph a subgraph of $K_{4,4}$?

Comment: @Amatuer: $K_{4,4}$ isn’t $2$-regular.

Comment: Yes, but $K_{4,4}$ is not $2$-regular, but $4$-regular.

Comment: In your example $G=P_2\bigcup P_5$, $\Delta(G)=2$, and $\chi'(G)=2$. The fact that you could find a proper edge coloring with more than $2$ colors does not prove that $\chi'(G)\gt2$. I can find a proper edge coloring of your graph with $5$ colors, so what?

Comment: In your drawing, why don't you color the two edges that cross each other blue, and the other three edges red?